# Add attribute to html element with php in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, hook

I need php code for functions.php (Wordpress) to add an attribute (data-priority="2") to an element if it have attribute: data-name="cf_post_wish_count"

I have

```
<th data-name="cf_post_wish_count"></th>
```

I need

```
<th data-name="cf_post_wish_count" data-priority="2"></th>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description this problem is more suited for JS/JQuery. You can do this on the frontend fairly simply:

```
$('th[data-name="cf_post_wish_count"]').each(function() {
     $(this).attr('data-priority', '2');
});
```